# Manually host a Blazor wasm application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I have a unique solution structure consisting of many project including these:

- **F.AspNetCore**: An Asp.net core MVC framework, having utilities and helpers for developing web applications.
- **F.Blazor**: A Blazor wasm app (also in my framework, referenced by **F.AspNetCore**) having helpful ready to use components.
- **A**: The entry point. This project passes configurations and domain models to **F.AspNetCore** and invokes its `startup`.
- **B**: A Blazor wasm app.

**A** and **B** are my guest projects. They can reference my framework projects but they must not be referenced by the framework.
I have come to realize that referencing a Blazor wasm project makes it run at the startup. (I don't know why and how it works. It would be good to know how it works under the hood.) I want to host my **B** project and the only way to do this is to reference it in my **F.AspNetCore** project, which is not possible because it's a framework and many other solutions are using it. Referencing project **B** in project **A** (the entry point) also doesn't work.
I would like to achieve either of these three:

1. Host my Blazor wasm app (project **B**) directly in my framework (**F.AspNetCore**) without referencing it. (Maybe through passing the assembly to the framework.)
2. Host my Blazor framework (**F.Blazor**) in **F.AspNetCore** (which is possible and I can do without a problem) then add the Blazor wasm application (project **B**) to it. Again with no reference in the framework projects.
3. Manually host project **B** if possible.

Comment: You can implement the second point, so what is your question? Project B is a complete Blazor project, refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for hosting.

Comment: @Chen "...then add the Blazor wasm application (project B) to it. Again with no reference in the framework projects." I can not add project B to F.Blazor without referencing it. I need to show project B pages and components. F.Blazor serves as a framework providing basic components and utilities.